# Django: NoReverse Match with regular expressions in URL

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a url go to the page of a users profile. I am using `(?P<pk>\d+)` in the urls to do this, however I am getting an error. Also if I remove the  that's linking this in the base.html the problem goes away. but then I don't have the link in the nabber...

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'user_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

In template /Users/garrettlove/Desktop/evverest/templates/base.html, error at line 23
Reverse for 'user_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
13      
14  <body>
15  
16      <nav>
17          <div class="container">
18              <a class="brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Evverest</a>
19              
20              <div class="navbar">
21                  <a class="nav-link btn" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
22                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
23                      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_profile' %}">New Color Set</a>
24                      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_logout' %}">Logout</a>
25                  {% else %}
26                      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_login' %}">Login</a>
27                      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
28                  {% endif %}
29              </div>
30          </div>
31      </nav>
32      
33      <div class="container">
```

It highlighted line 23 in the above code as the error.

Here is my code:

app urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from users import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.UserProfileView.as_view(),name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$',views.UserEditProfileView.as_view(),name='user-profile-edit'),
    url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='user_logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
]
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Evverest</title>

        <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="uft-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    </head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Evverest</a>

            <div class="navbar">
                <a class="nav-link btn" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_profile' %}">New Color Set</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_logout' %}">Logout</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_login' %}">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

app views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from users.forms import UserForm,UserProfileForm
from users.models import UserProfileInfo

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account now active")

        else:
            print("Login Unsuccessful")
            return HttpResponse("Username and/or password are not correct")

    else:
        return render(request,'login.html',{})

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request,'register.html',{
                                        'user_form':user_form,
                                        'profile_form':profile_form,
                                        'registered':registered
                                        })

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = UserProfileInfo
    ordering = ['-join_date']

class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = UserProfileInfo

class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = '/users_detail.html'
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    model = UserProfileInfo
```

Project urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from users import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomeView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^user/',include('users.urls',namespace='users')),
    url(r'^login/',views.user_login,name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
    url(r'^register/',views.register,name='register'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your first code block line 23 to

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_profile' user.id %}">New Color Set</a>
```

Comment: This worked, I'll accept the answer when it lets my in 4 minutes. thank you.